# How to convert select to linq without error of conversion?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to convert the code below to LINQ

```
SELECT bpac.cmp FROM bpac
UNION
SELECT bpai.cmp FROM bpai
GROUP BY cmp
ORDER BY cmp DESC
```

I am trying to get the first table but I get an error:

```
List<string> listaBpac = modelOff.bpacs.Where(p => p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge)
                                 .Select(p => new { p.cmp })
                                 .ToList();
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list "anonymous type: string cmp"' to 'system.collections.generic.list "anonymous type: string"'

Comment: With `new { p.cmp }` you initialize an anonymous type that has a single property `cmp` of type `string`. But you want to fill a `List<string>`, so you don't need that anonymous type. So simply select that property `p.cmp` directly without the anonymous type.

Comment: Your sql is inefficient because the `UNION` already removes duplicates(as opposed to `UNION ALL`), you don't need the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
List<string> listaBpac = modelOff.bpacs.Where(p => p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge)
                                    .Select(p => p.cmp)
                                    .ToList();
```

(you really need don't need the "new" keyword if you're returning a string member)

Comment: Something like; List<string> listpai = modelOff.bpai.Select(p => p.cmp).ToList().Union(listaBpac);